# ASP.NET loses data from form after postback - repeater inside updatepanel inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET web form where I have few checkboxes etc to make SearchCriteria object. When I click submit button I ask repeater1 to shew some records according to SearchCriteria. Inside repeater1 I have user control with updatepanel and another one repeater (ChildRepeater).

My problem: when I click send on the button after postback I lose all the data from form (eg that checkboxes was checked). Page is loading default values, but in my code I load default (all checkboxes checked) only if(!IsPostBack).
Of course I have "EnableViewState=true" in .aspx, I also tried to save data from form in session, but it also does not work (default values rewrite this settings).

When I have only one repeater (repeater1) my form after postback had all the data I put on it, so I think that there is some problem in updatepanel, but I don't know where exactly. 
Could you explain me why my form loses data after page reload? I can't see any mistake..

At the bottom are my files but I have n-tier architecture so... i put only necessary files from View/BLL (DAL and sql connection works fine)
Here you have a screen how it looks: [screen](http://imageshack.com/i/1a0ol5j)

ShowAgreements.aspx (it contains controls and parent repeater):

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table style="border: 1px solid #0000FF; width: 1250px">
                <tr style="background-color: #3d6db0; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">

                    <td style="width: 150px;">Numer</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Przedmiot umowy</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Odbiorca</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Dostawca</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Rodzaj umowy</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Charakter umowy</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Status wypożyczenia</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Data podpisania</td>
                    <td style="width: 150px;">Status</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>

      <itemtemplate>
        <uc1:FilesRepeaterControl runat="server" id="FilesRepeaterControl" />
          </itemtemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>         
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

ShowAgreements.aspx.cs:

```
AgreementsSearchCriteria AgreementSearchCriteriaObj = new AgreementsSearchCriteria();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Controller.ReadDostawcy();
            Controller.ReadOdbiorcy();
            Controller.ReadPracownikOdp();
        }

        Controller.ReadAllAgreements();
    }
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
             Agreement umowa = e.Item.DataItem as Agreement;
             BazaUmow.Controls.FilesRepeaterControl test = e.Item.FindControl("FilesRepeaterControl") as FilesRepeaterControl;
             test.umowa = umowa;
        }

    }


protected void szukaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid == true)
        {
            AddNaviPoint();
            Controller.ReadAllAgreements();
        }

    }
public AgreementSearchCollection BindUmowyResults
    {
        set 
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = value;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

FilesRepeaterControl.ascx
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilesRepeaterControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="BazaUmow.Controls.FilesRepeaterControl"  %>

```
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRozwin" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="btnRozwin_Click" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbl_numerUmowy" runat="server" OnClick="lbl_numerUmowy_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>

                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_przedmiotUmowy" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_odbiorca" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_dostawca" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_rodzajUmowy" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_charakterUmowy" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_statusWypozyczenia" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_dataPodpisania" runat="server" /></td>
                <td style="width: 150px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_statusUmowy" runat="server" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelFilesInfo" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="filesRptr" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="filesRptr_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style=" width:170px">
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <td style="width:170px;">Pliki umowy</td>

                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblPlikUmowy" runat="server" OnCommand="lblPlikUmowy_Command"></asp:LinkButton></td>

                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>

                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>


                <asp:Repeater ID="aneksyRptr" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="aneksyRptr_ItemDataBound">

                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style=" width:170px">
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <td style="width:170px;">Aneksy do umowy</td>

                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                       <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lblAneksUmowy" runat="server" OnCommand="lblAneksUmowy_Command"></asp:LinkButton></td>

                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>

                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>

                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

FilesRepeaterControl.ascx.cs (here we add data to parent repeater and fill two child repeaters when we click button btnRozwin)
    public Agreement umowa { get; set; }

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                lbl_numerUmowy.Text = umowa.numer_umowy.ToString();
                lbl_przedmiotUmowy.Text = umowa.przedmiot_umowy.ToString();
                lbl_odbiorca.Text = umowa.odbiorca_tekst.ToString();
                lbl_dostawca.Text = umowa.dostawca_tekst.ToString();
                lbl_rodzajUmowy.Text = umowa.rodzaj_umowy_tekst.ToString();
                lbl_charakterUmowy.Text = umowa.charakter_umowy_tekst.ToString();
                lbl_statusWypozyczenia.Text = umowa.status_wypozyczenia_tekst.ToString();
                lbl_dataPodpisania.Text = umowa.data_podpisania.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                lbl_statusUmowy.Text = umowa.status_umowy.ToString();
    }

    protected void filesRptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Plik plik = e.Item.DataItem as Plik;

            LinkButton lblPlikUmowy = e.Item.FindControl("lblPlikUmowy") as LinkButton;
            lblPlikUmowy.Text = plik.nazwa_pliku.ToString();
            lblPlikUmowy.CommandArgument = plik.guid + plik.rozszerzenie;

        }

    }


    protected void aneksyRptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Plik plik = e.Item.DataItem as Plik;

            LinkButton lblAneksUmowy = e.Item.FindControl("lblAneksUmowy") as LinkButton;
            lblAneksUmowy.Text = plik.nazwa_pliku.ToString();
            lblAneksUmowy.CommandArgument = plik.guid + plik.rozszerzenie;

        }

    }

    protected void btnRozwin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnRozwin.Text == "+")
        {
            filesRptr.Visible = true;
            aneksyRptr.Visible = true;

            filesRptr.DataSource = Controller.ReadFilesByAgreement(Convert.ToInt32(lbl_numerUmowy.Text), 1);
            filesRptr.DataBind();

            aneksyRptr.DataSource = Controller.ReadFilesByAgreement(Convert.ToInt32(lbl_numerUmowy.Text), 2);
            aneksyRptr.DataBind();

            btnRozwin.Text = "-";

        }

        else
        {
            filesRptr.Visible = false;
            aneksyRptr.Visible = false;
            btnRozwin.Text = "+";

        }

    }

    protected void lbl_numerUmowy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string numer_umowy = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
        Page.Response.Redirect("~/SeeAgreementData.aspx?numer=" + numer_umowy + "&email=" + Request.QueryString["email"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: try to post a simplified version on your code, aspx and code behind.

Comment: Can you please post your code that you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because  when you post back your update panel it refreshes a part(which is surrounded with update panel) of the page, so all data that was on that pannel is lost you can save all data that you need in ViewState

```
protected void UpdatePanelClick_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> checkedIds = new List<int>();
    //working with grid saving ids on list
    ViewState["saveUpdatePanelData"] = checkedIds;
}
```

than on pageload after postback you can get this data and initialize

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["saveUpdatePanelData"]!= null)
    {
        checkedIds = ViewState["saveUpdatePanelData"] as List<int>;
    }
}
```

it is how ViewState works.

Comment: So if I use only EnableViewState="true" on .aspx site it is not sufficient and I should use such list? And I find it strange but data from form (state of checkboxes etc - see screen that I added) are not in the updatepanel, so I think it should be save in enableviewstate, am I wrong?

Comment: @guitargirl by the way, when you click btnRozwin, you postback whole page on server( not the part of it). So thats why it initializes from your pageload. Try to put your btnRozwin inside updatepanel.You can save any information on ViewState obj.